# unable to spool through shell(ksh)

Tags: linux, ksh, hp-ux, sqlplus

I've written a shell script in which i've defined variables : `Last_Month`,`last_date` and `first_date` and i'm trying to execute the below sql from the shell :

`/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/bin/sqlplus -s user_name/passwd @effective_date.sql`

contents of `effective_date.sql`:

```
set heading off
set feedback off
set verify off
set pagesize 50000
set trimspool on
set wrap off
set newpage none
set linesize 2000

spool /home/dir/file_${Last_Month};

select * from table_1
where effective_date between to_date("$first_date",'dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date("$last_date",'dd-mm-yyyy');

spool off;
exit;
```

but on executing the shell, i'm getting below error:

```
SP2-0332: Cannot create spool file.
where effective_date between to_date("$first_date",'dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date("$last_date",'dd-mm-yyyy')
                                                                             *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "$last_date": invalid identifier


not spooling currently
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sqlplus` you should use different approach to the shell variables. Your command should become:

```
/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/bin/sqlplus -s user_name/passwd @effective_date.sql "$Last_Month" "$first_date" "$last_date"
```

and your sql script should be:

```
set heading off
set feedback off
set verify off
set pagesize 50000
set trimspool on
set wrap off
set newpage none
set linesize 2000

spool /home/dir/file_'&1';

select * from table_1
where effective_date between to_date('&2','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('&3','dd-mm-yyyy');

spool off;
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but after executing the shell, it's asking for the values, like `Enter value for 3:`, `Enter value for 2:`, `Enter value for 1:`....i don't want the prompt to be displayed.

Comment: Are variables set before execution? Do they have any special symbols inside? And you can try to put them in double quotes (see edited answer)

Comment: And try to add in `sqlplus` command the SID like `/sqlplus -s user_name/passwd@SID @effective_date.sql ...`